# How does measurement invariance work with demographic variables?

Tags: categorical-data, survey, measurement

I am running an analysis that includes an argument for measurement invariance which can be set as true or false. If true, item-response probabilities are constrained to be equal across groups.

When I look up measurement invariance, all the examples are about whether a question measures the same construct across equal groups. For example, if person 1 and person 2 have the same level of job satisfaction, will they both rate their job satisfaction the same on a questionnaire?

However, I am looking at demographic variables between two groups, men and women. One of the variables is marital status. I know that 93% of all single people in the sample are women. Does this mean anything? or should measurement invariance be assumed true, because the question "are you married?" measures the same construct between men and women?

Comment: You don't typically assess measurement invariance across demographics like "are you married." There's no need.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Thank you, I had a feeling it didn't fit the context! Apologies if this is a basic question, I'm new to the topic. I have tried to enter null for the invariance argument, but this returns an error.  Would you recommend entering invariance=false or invariance=true for the invariance argument? Not sure which would make more sense...